# finding specific pixels in a linear array openCV python livestream

Tags: python, opencv

In openCV I need to template match an object from a livestream, and then proceed to draw  two diagonal lines from the  bottom corners of that small object and create a linear array between those two diagonal lines to find/search for an interval that consists of just black-ish pixels surrounded by white-ish pixels. so moreso the question is just how do I create that linear array between those two lines that searches for that white pixelated line in the black box? keep in mind it is through a streamed video, not a still image.

Comment: Alrighty thanks! new user here. appreciate it.

Comment: Pictures help. You can post to some free hosting service and put the URLs in a comment

Comment: alrighty thanks for the tip fmw! i'll keep that in mind :)